# Java spring boot lazy fetch and json ignore not working

Tags: java, spring

I have a bord class and a bordrow class, meaning a bord has multiple bordrows in a one to many relation. Whenever I do a GET request on /bords I just want every bord model without the datetimes and without the rows, this is why I added lazy fetch and @JsonIgnore. However all attributes are sent on the request. What did I do wrong?

Bord.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Table(name = "bords")
@Entity
public class Bord
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String icon;

    private String background;

    @DateTimeFormat
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date created_at;

    @DateTimeFormat
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date updated_at;

    @DateTimeFormat
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date deleted_at;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bord", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BordRow> bordRows;

    public Bord() {
        bordRows = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

BordRow.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bord_rows")
public class BordRow
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bord_id", nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Bord bord;
}
```

BordController.java:

```
import com.jordibenck.scrumbords.scrumbords.entity.Bord;
import com.jordibenck.scrumbords.scrumbords.entity.User;
import com.jordibenck.scrumbords.scrumbords.repository.BordRepository;
import com.jordibenck.scrumbords.scrumbords.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/bords")
public class BordController
{
    @Autowired
    private BordRepository repository;

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Bord> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the annotations in your getters. and not your private fields

Hope it helps

Comment: The codehaus version is old and replaced by the xml as far as I know. Putting the JsonIgnore in the annotation of the getter does work. But it's strange since the ignore in BordRow on the bord field is working

Answer (score 0):

You should delete `@DateTimeFormat`. 
`@DateTimeFormat` has conflict with `@JsonIgnore.`